# AutoMapper requires Get Accessor to Set. CS0154 The property or indexer 'Id' cannot be used in this context because it lacks the get accessor

Tags: c#, automapper

The `Id` property in my `ViewModel` class can be set, but not gotten as the setter encrypts the value.  To get the value I have to use a either `GetEncryptedId()` or `GetDecryptedId()`.

**The ViewModel**

```
public ViewModel
{
    public int _id;
    public int Id { set { _id = Encrypt(value); }
    public Child ChildProperty {get; set; }
}

public Child
{
    public int Id {get; set;} 
    public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

The problem here is that for some reason Auto Mapper wants a get accessor so it can set a value.

```
public ViewModelProfile()
{
    CreateMap<Model, ViewModel>().ForMember(vm => vm.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.ChildProperty.Id))
}
```

This throws and error stating:

```
CS0154 The property or indexer 'Id' cannot be used in this context because it lacks the get accessor.
```

1. Why does Auto Mapper require a 'Get Accessor' to set a value.
2. Is there a configuration option to force a set and no get?

As a work around I've added a `Get { return -1; }`, but that is far from ideal.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I offer this in the spirit of trying to be helpful:  This violates section 5.2 of the Framework Design Guidelines (Cwalina, Abrams): "Do not provide set-only properties.  If a property getter cannot be provided, implement the functionality as a method instead."

Comment: The advice to restructure your API is still valuable -- set-only properties are a bad idea. Use an explicit method to set the value, or set the value only through the constructor. If you absolutely need a property to satisfy the demands of some other API, provide an adapter for that. Or just have `EncryptedID` and `UnencryptedID` properties; setting one updates both. Any one of these is vastly more intuitive than `O.Id = 5` doing something freaky with encryption under the covers.

Comment: Thank you @JeroenMostert that's solved the problem.  Pop your comments into an answer and I'll mark it as the one.

Comment: @Amy, thanks for the heads up.  It would make mapping a monotonous task if using methods. I would need to manually specify which method to use every time.  I will familiarise myself the the guidelines though as I've haven't heard of them before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a limitation of AutoMapper as such, but of the way its API is structured. The expression tree `vm => vm.Id` can't be constructed because this is, you've guessed it, a reference to the property getter, which isn't possible because there is no getter. Passing an expression tree as a strongly typed way of referencing a member is a standard technique; AutoMapper is by far not the only thing that would have problems with this. The fact that AutoMapper would not ultimately call the getter is immaterial in this case.

Fortunately, `ForMember` has an override that accepts the member name as a string, and using that avoids the problem with the expression tree:

```
CreateMap<Model, ViewModel>()
    .ForMember(nameof(ViewModel.Id), opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.ChildProperty.Id))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it:

```
 //Mapper Class

 public partial class AutoMapperConfig
 {
  public static MapperConfiguration UserLoginTovmLogin = null;

  public static void Mappings()
    {
        UserLoginTovmLogin = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        cfg.CreateMap<User_Login, VmLogin>()
        .ForMember(conf => conf.LoginId, dto => dto.MapFrom(src => src.Login_Id))
        .ForMember(conf => conf.Passsword, dto => dto.MapFrom(src => src.Passsword)));
    }
  }
   //In your Data login class
   VmLogin IAuthRepository.Login(string loginId)
    {
        VmLogin login = new VmLogin();
        var result = //Your Data Logic
        AutoMapperConfig.UserLoginTovmLogin.CreateMapper().Map(result, login);
        return login; 
    }
```